# Date convert to int in ISO format

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion, data-conversion

I wanted to make a date key from a date column in a table. What is the best manner to convert a `date` value into an `int` in a ISO format?

Comment: I know this is common in DW scenarios but I've not heard any argument I've been convinced by as to why not use a Date itself as the key in date dimensions

Comment: @MartinSmith Because DW is based off certain (no names!) pioneers in the field, who seem to have an affinity to `int` surrogate keys

Comment: Ok... so can you point us to an article by one of those experts on how converting dates to integers is such a whopping advantage?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use dates expressed as ISO integers but, if I did and even though the formula is a little bit longer that the CONVERT method, it's about 46% faster.  On a million rows, that's only a difference of 261 ms compared to 178 (on my box) but I work with billions of rows and every little bit helps.

Here's the formula that I would use if I had to do this type of thing...

```
YEAR(SomeDateTime)*10000+MONTH(SomeDateTime)*100+DAY(SomeDateTime)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution, have you better suggestion ?

```
select cast((convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112)) as int)
```

Comment: Is this an answer or is meant to an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73062750/edit) to your question? This doesn't read like an answer, as you *ask* a question in it.

Comment: is answer... have you better suggestion ?

Comment: varchar(8) is enough `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)`. [This page](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx) contains more convert options

Comment: *"is answer..."* Then word it like one; like I said, this reads like a question (more specifically, a lead on from your question).

Comment: _is there better?_ Define "better"? Likely there is none but only you know how to evaluate that question. Note that there is nothing "variable" about the 112 format. It is always 8 (not 10) characters.